# How to do log in in Flask with a given password

Tags: python, flask, authentication, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask to upload a file and do several operations with the data on it. I would like to do a webpage for log in before this main page where you can submit your data.

I have defined a password, `yjkuvaZq12@P`, and a username `datascientist5`. They will be the same for all my users, I will give it to the people who can access the website.

What I want is that anyone who wants to upload some data needs to register into the webpage using this username and this password. To do so, I have created a 
 html template with a box for username and a box for password that the people can fill.

However, I don't know where I have to specify in my code that my password and username are the ones mentioned above so when someone logs in, I can check if the username and passwords coincide so I can redirect them to the page to load the data.

What I have tried so far is:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.init_app(app)
db.init_app(app)



@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """For GET requests, display the login form. 
    For POSTS, login the current user by processing the form.

    """
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.get(form.email.data)
        if user:
            bcrypt =Bcrypt()
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                user.authenticated = True
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            return redirect(url_for("app.home"))
return render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

However I don't know where or how I should specify my password. Right now it doesn't matter what I enter as password online that I get access to the page where I can submit data.

I am very new to this so any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you didn't do anything if the password is wrong.
If the password is wrong you need to raise an error and stop access:

```
if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
    user.authenticated = True
else:
    raise HTTPBadRequest('Wrong password')
```